# Import Error in django view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is my project directory

```
├── feed
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20180722_1431.py
│   │  
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │ 
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── feed
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       ├── footer.html
│   │       ├── header.html
│   │       ├── hindustantimes.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── ndtv.html
│   │       ├── News_Home.html
│   │       ├── republic.html
│   │       └── tredns.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── twitter
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── twitter_credentials.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── trends.py
│   │   ├── tweets.py
│   │   └── twitter_credentials.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── os
├── pironews
│   ├── __init__.py
│   |
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   |
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── __pycache__
```

I want to import the trends.py file in my views:

I am doing the following in the views file

```
from pironews.feed.twitter.trends import main

def twitter_trend(request):
    output = main()
    print(output)
    return HttpResponse(output, content_type='text/plain')
```

This is my trends.py file

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys # used for the storage class
import requests
import pycurl # used for curling
import base64 # used for encoding string
import urllib.parse # used for enconding
from io import StringIO# used for curl buffer grabbing
import io
import re
import json # used for decoding json token
import time # used for stuff to do with the rate limiting
from time import sleep # used for rate limiting
from time import gmtime, strftime # used for gathering time
import twitter_credentials

OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'

class Storage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = ''
        self.line = 0

    def store(self, buf):
        self.line = self.line + 1
        self.contents = "%s%i: %s" % (self.contents, self.line, buf)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contents


def getYear():
    return strftime("%Y", gmtime())

def getMonth():
    return strftime("%m", gmtime())

def getDay():
    return strftime("%d", gmtime())

def getHour():
    return strftime("%H", gmtime())

def getMinute():
    return strftime("%M", gmtime())

def generateFileName():
    return getYear()+"-"+getMonth()+"-"+getDay()+""

# grabs the rate limit remaining from the headers
def grab_rate_limit_remaining(headers):
    limit = ''
    h = str(headers).split('\n')
    for line in h:
        if 'x-rate-limit-remaining:' in line:
            limit = line[28:-1]
    return limit

# grabs the time the rate limit expires
def grab_rate_limit_time(headers):
    x_time = ''
    h = str(headers).split('\n')
    for line in h:
        if 'x-rate-limit-reset:' in line:
            x_time = line[24:-1]
    return x_time

# obtains the bearer token
def get_bearer_token(consumer_key,consumer_secret):
    # enconde consumer key
    consumer_key = urllib.parse.quote(consumer_key)
    # encode consumer secret
    consumer_secret = urllib.parse.quote(consumer_secret)
#   print(type(consumer_secret))
    # create bearer token
    bearer_token = consumer_key+':'+consumer_secret
    # base64 encode the token
    base64_encoded_bearer_token = base64.b64encode(bearer_token.encode('utf-8'))
    # set headers
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + base64_encoded_bearer_token.decode('utf-8') + "",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Length": "29"}

    response = requests.post(OAUTH2_TOKEN, headers=headers, data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'})
    to_json = response.json()
    return to_json['access_token']


def grab_a_tweet(bearer_token, tweet_id):
    # url
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json"
    formed_url ='?id='+tweet_id+'&result_type=popular' #include_entities=true
    headers = [
    str("GET /1.1/statuses/show.json"+formed_url+" HTTP/1.1"),
    str("Host: api.twitter.com"),
    str("User-Agent: jonhurlock Twitter Application-only OAuth App Python v.1"),
    str("Authorization: Bearer "+bearer_token+"")
    ]
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    tweet = ''
    retrieved_headers = Storage()
    pycurl_connect = pycurl.Curl()
    pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl_connect.URL, url+formed_url) # used to tell which url to go to
    pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl_connect.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write) # used for generating output
    pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl_connect.HTTPHEADER, headers) # sends the customer headers above
    pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl_connect.HEADERFUNCTION, retrieved_headers.store)
    #pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl_connect.VERBOSE, True) # used for debugging, really helpful if you want to see what happens
    pycurl_connect.perform() # perform the curl
    tweet += buf.getvalue().decode('UTF-8') # grab the data
    pycurl_connect.close() # stop the curl
    #print retrieved_headers
    pings_left = grab_rate_limit_remaining(retrieved_headers)
    reset_time = grab_rate_limit_time(retrieved_headers)
    current_time = time.mktime(time.gmtime())
    return {'tweet':tweet, '_current_time':current_time, '_reset_time':reset_time, '_pings_left':pings_left}

def main():
    consumer_key = twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_KEY # put your apps consumer key here
    consumer_secret = twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_SECRET # put your apps consumer secret here

    bearer_token = get_bearer_token(consumer_key,consumer_secret)

    tweet = grab_a_tweet(bearer_token,'23424848') # grabs a single tweet & some extra bits
    print(type(tweet['tweet']))
    print(tweet['_current_time'])
    json_obj = json.loads(tweet['tweet'])

    for i in json_obj:
        for j in i['trends']:
            print(j['name'])
```

But when I run the server I am getting following error

```
PiroProject/pironews/feed/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pironews.feed.twitter.trends import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pironews.feed'
```

What should I do now?

Comment: What your INSTALLED_APPS settings looks like ?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'feed',
]

Comment: can you post the output of ```~$ echo $PYTHONPATH```

Comment: Do i need to run this command echo $PYTHONPATH. If yes then I am getting a blank line.

Comment: You will have to import from the perspective of your PYTHONPATH. It should be your project folder, so the import should be `from feed.twitter.trends import main`. `pironews` will be the folder at the bottom of your listing. BTW There's a typo in a template's file name.

Comment: use ```export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project```

Comment: @MousaHalaseh He should get the import right instead of messing with the PYTHONPATH which would have a lot of side effects.

Comment: @klausD of course that would be better.

Comment: @imsaiful first comment from KlausD is the answer.

Comment: This is the answer There are two things which needs to be done.

You need to do from .trends import main in the ____init___.py file twitter folder

You can then import in the view.py file from .twitter import main         thanks everyone

Comment: `from .twitter` actually means the same as `from feed.twitter` because `views.py` is in `feed` app too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things which needs to be done.

- You need to do `from .trends import main` in the ____init___.py file twitter  folder
- You can then import in the view.py file `from .twitter import main`

Comment: It is giving  error File "/home/imsaiful/PiroProject/pironews/feed/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    from twitter import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twitter'

Comment: could you use `from .twitter import main` this line and see?

Comment: Working fine SIr.

Comment: Glad I could help. Kindly accept the answer, so that others can get help from this

Comment: Whenever any of your questions are answered correctly, you should click on the tick button to accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `from pironews.feed.twitter.trends import main` to `from twitter.trends import main`.

Comment: Not helpful giving this error  from twitter.trends import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twitter'

Comment: I don't understand the need to include `pironews.feed` if `twitter` directory lies in the same directory as `views.py`. `from twitter.trends import main` should work. Is the error same after replacing `from pironews.feed.twitter.trends import main` to `from twitter.trends import main` ?

Comment: Sir @invincibly cool Yes getting this error after replacing File "/home/imsaiful/PiroProject/pironews/feed/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    from twitter.trends import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twitter'